# change ofWord to of Word, and ignore offer, office, off etc

Tags: search, replace

I OCRed a document but has this problem: some spaces between "of" and the word after are gone and I need to add a space between "of" and "word". Is there any way to do it? And also to avoid adding space after of in the words such as offer, off, often, office etc which start with "of".

Comment: Something like `:%s/of\zs./ &`? To make it work for your document we will probably need more details on the edge cases of your file.

Comment: could you clarify what `\zs./ &` means?

Comment: `\zs` is the beginning of what we will match. So we want to match any single character (`.`) following `of`. In the replacement part of the expression `&` is what was matched (the single character after `of`). If your file contains both `ofword` and `of word` you probably want to replace `.` with `\w` to match only word class characters.

Comment: Thanks, it works. how to exclude words like often, offer, etc. in the replacement? (now I add `gc` at the end to confirm each replacement).

Comment: Please edit your question with _all_ your requirements, the comments are not meant to do that.

Comment: Add the `c` flag to your `:s` command and decide on a case by case base